# This error 'int' object is not callable is hampering me

Tags: python

```
import sys

from random import gauss

from math import exp,sqrt
import math
from scipy.stats import norm
from math import *

def american_option(type_s, S0, sigma, r, d, K, N, T):
    d1= log(float(S0)/K)+ ((r-d+ sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*sqrt(T))
    d2= d1- sigma*sqrt(T)

    if type_s== 'call':
        m =  S0*exp(-d*T)*N*(d1)- K*exp(-r*T)*N*(d2)
    elif type_s== 'put':
        m =  K*exp(-r*T)*N*(-d2)- S0*exp(-d*T)*N*(-d1)
    return m
american_option(100, 0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 110, 12, 365,)
```

## Error

in american_option(S0, sigma, r, d, K, N, T, type)
      4 
      5     if type== 'call':
      6         m =  S0*exp(-d*T)*N(d1)- K*exp(-r*T)*N(d2)
      7     elif type== 'put':
      8         m =  K*exp(-r*T)*N(-d2)- S0*exp(-d*T)*N(-d1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

m =  S0*exp(-d*T)*N*(d1)- K*exp(-r*T)*N*(d2)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Show how the function is called. And have you looked up the error? This is very common. I'd guess though that N is a number, which means you're trying to use a number as a function when you write `N(d1)`. There is no implicit multiplication. You always need to use `*`.

Comment: can you elaborate? what is causing the error? what is the desired output?

Comment: If your code causes an error, ou should post the Traceback, formatted as code.

Comment: This is the error : TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-26b2a711da39> in <module>()
----> 1 american_option(100, 0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 110, 12, 365,'call')

<ipython-input-53-604588970e3d> in american_option(S0, sigma, r, d, K, N, T, type)
      4 
      5     if type== 'call':
----> 6         m =  S0*exp(-d*T)*N(d1)- K*exp(-r*T)*N(d2)
      7     elif type== 'put':
      8         m =  K*exp(-r*T)*N(-d2)- S0*exp(-d*T)*N(-d1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: You are trying to call something that you think is a function but is really an integer. You need to show us the error so we know where it is and to show us some input that produces the error. You may need to break one line into several to find out which thing is the problem, and you can also use print statements to see what you have verses what you think you have.

Comment: Please edit your question with that error. And put it in a code block (the {} thing) so we can read it.

Comment: Just made the change

Comment: The code you posted is not quite the code you ran. Notice `N(d2)` in the trace when the code is `N*(d2)`. That's the problem (you didn't have the multiplication symbol) and its already fixed in your code.

Comment: For future reference, its best to put the entire trace into the question, not just the error line. Most python programmers are used to scanning them quickly (except the really good ones who've never seen one!) and they provide more context for the problem.